# Question about cointegration

Tags: cointegration

I was reading about [cointegration](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/HoldingPen/NobelPrizeInfo.pdf)  (page 5) and it said

> "If a linear combination of combination of a set of $I(1)$ variables is
>   $I(0)$, then the variables are cointegrated."

Does this mean that any 2 $I(1)$ variables, no matter what they are will definitely be cointegrated? If yes, can you give the proof. If no, could you give a counterexample. I'm very curious about this topic.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. It is said that there must be some particular linear combination of $I(1)$ variables, but there may not exist one. In that case we have so called spurious regression, you may find an example [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/cointegration.pdf). We [say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointegration) that two or more time series are cointegrated if they share a common stochastic drift, so it is possible for variables to be $I(1)$ and to have different stochastic drifts.

Comment: Can you please say how the book is called where you took the example explaining the cointegration? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have
$$x_t = x_{t-1} + \delta_t, y_t = y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$
with obvious assumptions ($\epsilon_t$ are i.i.d., $\delta_t$ are i.i.d. and independent of $\epsilon_t$, $x_0$ and $y_0$ are independent of each other and $\epsilon$ and $\delta$). Then no matter how hard you try, for $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$, $ax_t + by_t$ will be an $I(1)$ process: it is itself non-stationary, while its first difference is $a\delta_t + b\epsilon_t$ is white noise.

So if anything, cointegration should be viewed as a much rarer phenomenon than lack of cointegration. Examples of cointegration would require special constructions. Define $z_t = z_{t-1} + \gamma \delta_t + \nu_t$ for some $\gamma\neq0$, where $\nu_t \sim ARMA(p,q)$. Then $z_t$ and $x_t$ are cointegrated, as $z_t - \gamma x_t = z_0 - \gamma x_0 + \nu_t$ is now stationary.